# webkit blur transition with positioned elements

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I was trying to create a blur/unblur transition when clicking a button.

I have managed to get this working on basic elements, however as soon as I add any kind of positioning to the elements the unblur stops working. I created a jsfiddle to show this 
http://jsfiddle.net/NLpRy/

I'm currently using

```
-webkit-filter: initial;
filter: initial;
```

to set the initial 'unblurred' state.

Is there a bug with the filters when using positioned elements?

*Note: I have tried the following code and although it does work, I can't use it as a solution as it breaks my other animations elsewhere.*

```
-webkit-filter: blur(0);
filter: blur(0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me, probably will get solved in some future version of the browser.

In the meanwhile, I got it fixed using the 3d trick, transform: translateZ(0px);

```
.page {
    -webkit-filter: none;
    filter: none;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 1.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 3s ease-out;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
    transform: translateZ(0px);
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NLpRy/1/)

Comment: wow that's awesome! Any idea why adding the translateZ fixes it though?

Comment: The child elements are not blurred, it's the page that is. Then, the browser has to *link* the rendering of the child to the rendering of the page. Somehow, this fails in the transition as you use it here. Having the page rendered transformed in 3D space, also links the rendering of the children to the rendering of the page, and this one doesn't fail